# MSSQL update ResultSet using JDBC

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

MS SQL Server 2019 running on Windows 10, with Java 1.8.0_152 and mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;loginTimeout=30;user=abc;password=def;trustServerCertificate=true");
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    
    String sql = "use AdventureWorks2019; select * from [HumanResources].[Department]";
    ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    rs2.moveToInsertRow();
```

yields:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set is not updatable.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:237)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.throwNotUpdatable(SQLServerResultSet.java:531)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.verifyResultSetIsUpdatable(SQLServerResultSet.java:537)
at com.microsoft.sql`enter code here`server.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.moveToInsertRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:5050)
at com.mtas.test.SQL.main(SQL.java:21)
```

line 21 being the final line shown.

The DDL is:

```
CREATE TABLE [HumanResources].[Department](
[DepartmentID] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [dbo].[Name] NOT NULL,
[GroupName] [dbo].[Name] NOT NULL,
[ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,


CONSTRAINT [PK_Department_DepartmentID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DepartmentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is a copy of a Microsoft example. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Why `use AdventureWorks2019;` in the `sql` string? Why not specify the correct database name in the connection parameters?

Comment: In my actual app I run against many databases, all of the same design,  passing the database name and connection to the method which implements the sql. But you have identified the problem.  Placing the database in the connection string, or using the setCatalog method before creating the statement works.  I had not realised the "use dbname" feature doesn't allow for updatable resultsets.  I am very used to seeing "use dbname" whilst using SSMS.  Also getConcurrency() and getType() on the resultset whilst using "use dbname" yields that the resultset is updatable even though it plainly isn't.

Comment: I have used the "use dbname" method in jdbc for years without issue, but not with updatable resultsets.  Is this a bug in jdbc, or is it a documented feature?

Comment: Well, two possibilities come to mind: 1) the `LOGIN7` packet of the MS-TDS protocol has an options flag that can cause a warning message to be issued by the server to the client whenever a `use <database>` statement is executed, which could be messing with the JDBC cursor, or 2) it could just be that it's two statements in a batch messing with the JDBC cursor. `select *` is bad practice, by the way, but what happens if you just change the `sql` string to `select * from [AdventureWorks2019].[HumanResources].[Department];` ?

Comment: It looks like you are correct with 1).  If I include the databasename in the select then it works.  But if I execute the Use in a statement by itself and then execute the select as originally coded then that works too.  Putting the two into the same statement doesn't.  So it looks like the jdbc driver is not handling the response.  I know the select * is not good practice!!